# SQL Query - Merge two types of objects with the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to find PC model pairs with the same speed and memory. These pairs are listed only once.
Here is my data and desired results:

- desired results:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkvWV.png
- data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuog8.png

I did get results but the query is too long, I know there is a shorter way. Hope everyone help me.

Here is my query

```
DECLARE @FOR INT = 1
DECLARE @SPEED INT
DECLARE @RAM INT
DECLARE @MODEL INT
DECLARE @LIST TABLE(SPEED INT, RAM INT)
DECLARE @LISTMODEL TABLE(MODEL INT)
DECLARE @RESULT TABLE(PC1 INT, PC2 INT)
DECLARE @RESULTREAL TABLE(COUPLE NVARCHAR(20), SPEED INT, RAM INT)
DECLARE @COUNT INT
    WHILE(1=1)
    BEGIN
        IF(NOT EXISTS(SELECT TOP(1) SPEED FROM @LIST))
        BEGIN
            INSERT @LIST(SPEED,RAM)
            SELECT speed,ram
            FROM VW_count
        END
        BREAK
    END
    SET @COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(SPEED) FROM @LIST) 
    WHILE @FOR <= @COUNT
    BEGIN
        SET @SPEED = (SELECT KETQUA.SPEED FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SPEED) AS STT, SPEED FROM @LIST) AS KETQUA WHERE KETQUA.STT = 1)
        SET @RAM = (SELECT KETQUA.RAM FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAM) AS STT, RAM FROM @LIST) AS KETQUA WHERE KETQUA.STT = 1)
        IF @SPEED IS NULL
        BEGIN
            BREAK
        END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                IF(EXISTS(SELECT speed FROM PC WHERE speed = @SPEED AND ram = @RAM))
                BEGIN
                    INSERT @LISTMODEL(MODEL)
                    SELECT model FROM PC WHERE speed = @SPEED AND ram = @RAM
                    INSERT @RESULT(PC1,PC2)
                    SELECT DISTINCT L1.MODEL, L2.MODEL FROM @LISTMODEL AS L1 , @LISTMODEL AS L2
                    INSERT @RESULTREAL(COUPLE,SPEED,RAM)
                    SELECT CONCAT(R1.PC1, ', ', R1.PC2), @SPEED, @RAM FROM @RESULT R1 WHERE R1.PC1 > R1.PC2 OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @RESULT R2 WHERE R2.PC1 = R1.PC2 AND R1.PC2 = R2.PC1)
                END
                DELETE @RESULT
                DELETE @LISTMODEL
            END
    SET @FOR = @FOR + 1
    DELETE TOP(1) FROM @LIST 
    CONTINUE
    END
    SELECT * FROM @RESULTREAL
```

Comment: Please do not add sample data as an image. We need to create temporary tables to reproduce your error, and nobody likes to type in all the data from an image

Comment: @GuidoG sorry about this, how to post query data online?

Comment: @KhoaHoàng . . . You could check out [this help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more information about formatting your posts on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normally a bad idea to use procedural statements when you could also use set-based logic.

You could make a SELECT query using a self-join on table `[PC]` based on the value of the `[speed]` and `[ram]` fields, but where the `[model]` value of the second table is larger than that of the first table. Something like this:

```
DECLARE @RESULTREAL TABLE(COUPLE NVARCHAR(20), SPEED INT, RAM INT);

INSERT INTO @RESULTREAL
SELECT
  CAST(T1.[model] AS NVARCHAR) + N', ' + CAST(T2.[model] AS NVARCHAR),
  T1.[speed],
  T1.[ram]
FROM
  [PC] AS T1
  INNER JOIN [PC] AS T2 ON
    T2.[speed] = T1.[speed] AND
    T2.[ram] = T1.[ram]
WHERE
  T2.[model] > T1.[model];
```

Comment: Thank you for my help with my sql writing skills. I have complicated the problem up and find it difficult to use the loop.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Yes, loops are difficult in SQL. And slow. ;) You should try to avoid them as much as you can. Most SQL querying related challenges can be solved using set-based querying logic, for which the database engine is optimized. So personally I am actually quite glad that loops and cursors are so ugly in SQL. ;)

Comment: I have another question, and I also use the loop. Can you help me make the query shorter without using the while? . Ill post it later. thank u

Comment: Sure. I will take a look at it. I will try to keep an eye on the list of new questions, but perhaps you could also post a comment here with a link to your new question to notify me explicitly.

Comment: I posted new post , here is a link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66670005/sql-query-merge-different-rows-according-to-date-conditions . Thank u .