# Merge different rows according to date conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I found this post on SO, but it solved with bigquery, I tried it with SQL query and I have problems using too many variables and loops. Despite the results, this query may not be optimal. Hope everyone help me

I have a table with playid, userid, created, and stopped. I want to merge certain rows by keeping the earliest created and the latest stopped within 120 minutes from the earliest created.

Desired Result:

| playid | userid | created | stopped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:29:58.559858 | 2021-01-30 04:16:25.948311 |
| 8 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:26:28.968568 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 21 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.529666 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.532786 |
| 23 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547111 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.464444 |

Data:

| playid | userid | created | stopped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:29:58.559858 | 2021-01-30 02:40:56.558436 |
| 2 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:41:24.023358 | 2021-01-30 02:55:24.112713 |
| 3 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:57:30.178579 | 2021-01-30 03:11:14.866678 |
| 4 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:11:41.098424 | 2021-01-30 03:22:50.155918 |
| 5 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:23:20.545288 | 2021-01-30 03:36:37.027486 |
| 6 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:46:10.237971 | 2021-01-30 03:59:17.526151 |
| 7 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:59:57.020326 | 2021-01-30 04:16:25.948311 |
| 8 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:26:28.968568 | 2021-01-30 04:30:11.863079 |
| 9 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:30:14.43786 | 2021-01-30 04:41:42.231915 |
| 10 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:43:17.669945 | 2021-01-30 04:45:10.443101 |
| 11 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:45:14.50346 | 2021-01-30 04:47:07.082114 |
| 12 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:47:10.334574 | 2021-01-30 04:49:30.96017 |
| 13 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:49:34.146011 | 2021-01-30 04:50:54.45988 |
| 14 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:50:57.948305 | 2021-01-30 05:11:01.246284 |
| 15 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:39:29.387396 | 2021-01-30 05:41:39.508654 |
| 16 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:41:44.524951 | 2021-01-30 05:43:38.231266 |
| 17 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:43:40.785809 | 2021-01-30 05:54:40.711381 |
| 18 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:55:10.851725 | 2021-01-30 05:58:24.262351 |
| 19 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:58:29.43821 | 2021-01-30 06:00:50.870644 |
| 20 | a01 | 2021-01-30 06:00:54.168696 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210234 |
| 21 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.529666 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.349479 |
| 22 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053136 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.532786 |
| 23 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547111 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.564802 |
| 24 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.248499 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.21787 |
| 25 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373145 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.099898 |
| 26 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.20448 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993751 |
| 27 | a01 | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.141051 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.464444 |

Here is my query

```
DECLARE @FAKELIST TABLE(PLAYID INT, USERID VARCHAR(10), CREATED DATETIME, [STOPPED] DATETIME)
DECLARE @result TABLE(PLAYID INT, USERID VARCHAR(10), CREATED DATETIME, [STOPPED] DATETIME)
INSERT @FAKELIST(PLAYID, USERID, CREATED, [STOPPED]) SELECT * FROM MyTable
        
DECLARE @CREATED DATETIME
DECLARE @STOPPED1 DATETIME
DECLARE @STOPPED2 DATETIME
declare @playid int
declare @userid varchar(10)

while(exists (select top(1) * from @FAKELIST))
begin
    set @CREATED = (select top(1) CREATED from @FAKELIST)
    set @playid =(select top(1) PLAYID from @FAKELIST)
    set @userid=(select top(1) USERID from @FAKELIST)   
     
    set @STOPPED1 = (select [STOPPED] from @FAKELIST order by PLAYID OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)  
    set @STOPPED2 = (select [STOPPED] from @FAKELIST order by PLAYID OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)  
            while(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@CREATED,@STOPPED2) <120)
                begin
                    delete from @FAKELIST where [STOPPED] =@STOPPED1
                    set @STOPPED1 = (select [STOPPED] from @FAKELIST order by PLAYID OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)
                    set @STOPPED2 = (select [STOPPED] from @FAKELIST order by PLAYID OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)  
                end
                insert into @result(PLAYID,USERID,CREATED,[STOPPED]) values (@playid,@userid,@CREATED,@STOPPED1)
                delete from @FAKELIST where PLAYID = @playid                
                delete from @FAKELIST where [STOPPED] = @STOPPED1   
end
SELECT * FROM @result
```

Comment: would you please clarify a bit how you are selecting you desired output. What's the logic behind?

Comment: Then instead of playid 21 wouldn't the answer be playid 20?

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur playid 20 has stopped results, so created will be in playid 21

Comment: @KhoaHoàng . .  .Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I will try to explain the query part by part (I am afraid that I might not a good explainer):

Schema and insert statement:

```
 create table data (playid int, userid varchar(10), created datetime,stopped datetime);
 insert into data values(1,'a01','01/30/2021 02:29:58.560','01/30/2021 02:40:56.558');
 insert into data values(2,'a01','01/30/2021 02:41:24.023','01/30/2021 02:55:24.113');
 insert into data values(3,'a01','01/30/2021 02:57:30.179','01/30/2021 03:11:14.867');
 insert into data values(4,'a01','01/30/2021 03:11:41.098','01/30/2021 03:22:50.156');
 insert into data values(5,'a01','01/30/2021 03:23:20.545','01/30/2021 03:36:37.027');
 insert into data values(6,'a01','01/30/2021 03:46:10.238','01/30/2021 03:59:17.526');
 insert into data values(7,'a01','01/30/2021 03:59:57.020','01/30/2021 04:16:25.948');
 insert into data values(8,'a01','01/30/2021 04:26:28.969','01/30/2021 04:30:11.863');
 insert into data values(9,'a01','01/30/2021 04:30:14.438','01/30/2021 04:41:42.232');
 insert into data values(10,'a01','01/30/2021 04:43:17.670','01/30/2021 04:45:10.443');
 insert into data values(11,'a01','01/30/2021 04:45:14.503','01/30/2021 04:47:07.082');
 insert into data values(12,'a01','01/30/2021 04:47:10.335','01/30/2021 04:49:30.960');
 insert into data values(13,'a01','01/30/2021 04:49:34.146','01/30/2021 04:50:54.460');
 insert into data values(14,'a01','01/30/2021 04:50:57.948','01/30/2021 05:11:01.246');
 insert into data values(15,'a01','01/30/2021 05:39:29.387','01/30/2021 05:41:39.509');
 insert into data values(16,'a01','01/30/2021 05:41:44.525','01/30/2021 05:43:38.231');
 insert into data values(17,'a01','01/30/2021 05:43:40.786','01/30/2021 05:54:40.711');
 insert into data values(18,'a01','01/30/2021 05:55:10.852','01/30/2021 05:58:24.262');
 insert into data values(19,'a01','01/30/2021 05:58:29.438','01/30/2021 06:00:50.871');
 insert into data values(20,'a01','01/30/2021 06:00:54.169','01/30/2021 06:12:37.210');
 insert into data values(21,'a01','01/30/2021 14:41:01.530','01/30/2021 14:53:01.349');
 insert into data values(22,'a01','01/30/2021 14:53:48.053','01/30/2021 15:05:09.533');
 insert into data values(23,'a01','01/31/2021 15:11:08.547','01/31/2021 15:11:37.565');
 insert into data values(24,'a01','01/31/2021 15:11:40.248','01/31/2021 15:13:40.218');
 insert into data values(25,'a01','01/31/2021 15:13:59.373','01/31/2021 15:31:54.100');
 insert into data values(26,'a01','01/31/2021 15:32:23.204','01/31/2021 15:46:33.994');
 insert into data values(27,'a01','01/31/2021 16:55:19.141','01/31/2021 17:03:43.464');
```

First Part of Query:

```
     select d.playid,d.userid,d.created,d.stopped,dt.minstopped from data d
      outer apply (
      select max(stopped) minstopped from data dt 
      where  d.playid<dt.playid and datediff(minute,d.created,dt.stopped)<=120
      and d.userid=dt.userid)dt
```

In above query I have added a new column named `minstopped` which will calculate the maximum stopped date time. The logic behind is when we are calculating `minstopped` for first row we will calculate max(sopped) from all the rows having stopped date no greater than created date from first row plus 120 minutes.

Output:

| playid | userid | created | stopped | minstopped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:29:58.560 | 2021-01-30 02:40:56.557 | 2021-01-30 04:16:25.947 |
| 2 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:41:24.023 | 2021-01-30 02:55:24.113 | 2021-01-30 04:41:42.233 |
| 3 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:57:30.180 | 2021-01-30 03:11:14.867 | 2021-01-30 04:50:54.460 |
| 4 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:11:41.097 | 2021-01-30 03:22:50.157 | 2021-01-30 05:11:01.247 |
| 5 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:23:20.547 | 2021-01-30 03:36:37.027 | 2021-01-30 05:11:01.247 |
| 6 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:46:10.237 | 2021-01-30 03:59:17.527 | 2021-01-30 05:43:38.230 |
| 7 | a01 | 2021-01-30 03:59:57.020 | 2021-01-30 04:16:25.947 | 2021-01-30 05:58:24.263 |
| 8 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:26:28.970 | 2021-01-30 04:30:11.863 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 9 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:30:14.437 | 2021-01-30 04:41:42.233 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 10 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:43:17.670 | 2021-01-30 04:45:10.443 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 11 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:45:14.503 | 2021-01-30 04:47:07.083 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 12 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:47:10.337 | 2021-01-30 04:49:30.960 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 13 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:49:34.147 | 2021-01-30 04:50:54.460 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 14 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:50:57.947 | 2021-01-30 05:11:01.247 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 15 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:39:29.387 | 2021-01-30 05:41:39.510 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 16 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:41:44.527 | 2021-01-30 05:43:38.230 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 17 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:43:40.787 | 2021-01-30 05:54:40.710 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 18 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:55:10.853 | 2021-01-30 05:58:24.263 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 19 | a01 | 2021-01-30 05:58:29.437 | 2021-01-30 06:00:50.870 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
| 20 | a01 | 2021-01-30 06:00:54.170 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 | *null* |
| 21 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |
| 22 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | *null* |
| 23 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |
| 24 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |
| 25 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |
| 26 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |
| 27 | a01 | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | *null* |

Second part to make a group with all the rows where stopped date is more than 120 minutes from the created date of first row from previous group. So we now have a group of rows for every 120 minutes gap between created date and stopped date.

```
 with cte as
    (
      select d.playid,d.userid,d.created,d.stopped,dt.minstopped from data d
      outer apply (
      select max(stopped) minstopped from data dt 
      where  d.playid<dt.playid and datediff(minute,d.created,dt.stopped)<=120
      and d.userid=dt.userid)dt 
    ),
    cte2 as 
    (
    select top 1 *, 1 level from cte order by playid 
    union all
    select cte.* ,level+2 level from cte inner join cte2 on cte.stopped>cte2.minstopped
    )
    select * from cte2
    order by level, playid
```

> ```
> playid | userid | created                 | stopped                 | minstopped              | level
> -----: | :----- | :---------------------- | :---------------------- | :---------------------- | ----:
>      1 | a01    | 2021-01-30 02:29:58.560 | 2021-01-30 02:40:56.557 | 2021-01-30 04:16:25.947 |     1
>      8 | a01    | 2021-01-30 04:26:28.970 | 2021-01-30 04:30:11.863 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>      9 | a01    | 2021-01-30 04:30:14.437 | 2021-01-30 04:41:42.233 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>     10 | a01    | 2021-01-30 04:43:17.670 | 2021-01-30 04:45:10.443 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>     11 | a01    | 2021-01-30 04:45:14.503 | 2021-01-30 04:47:07.083 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>     12 | a01    | 2021-01-30 04:47:10.337 | 2021-01-30 04:49:30.960 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>     13 | a01    | 2021-01-30 04:49:34.147 | 2021-01-30 04:50:54.460 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>     14 | a01    | 2021-01-30 04:50:57.947 | 2021-01-30 05:11:01.247 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>     15 | a01    | 2021-01-30 05:39:29.387 | 2021-01-30 05:41:39.510 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>     16 | a01    | 2021-01-30 05:41:44.527 | 2021-01-30 05:43:38.230 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>     17 | a01    | 2021-01-30 05:43:40.787 | 2021-01-30 05:54:40.710 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>     18 | a01    | 2021-01-30 05:55:10.853 | 2021-01-30 05:58:24.263 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>     19 | a01    | 2021-01-30 05:58:29.437 | 2021-01-30 06:00:50.870 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |     3
>     20 | a01    | 2021-01-30 06:00:54.170 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 | null                    |     3
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     3
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     3
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     3
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     3
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     3
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     3
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     3
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     21 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 14:53:01.350 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     22 | a01    | 2021-01-30 14:53:48.053 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 | null                    |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     5
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     23 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 15:11:37.567 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     24 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:11:40.247 | 2021-01-31 15:13:40.217 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     25 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:13:59.373 | 2021-01-31 15:31:54.100 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     26 | a01    | 2021-01-31 15:32:23.203 | 2021-01-31 15:46:33.993 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
>     27 | a01    | 2021-01-31 16:55:19.140 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 | null                    |     7
> ```

Final Query:
In final query we will chose first row with the minimum playid from each group. In that way we will get only rows having more than 120 mintuts gap between created date of a row and stopped date of next row.

> ```
>  with cte as
>    (
>     select d.playid,d.userid,d.created,d.stopped,dt.minstopped from data d
>     outer apply (
>     select max(stopped) minstopped from data dt 
>     where  d.playid<dt.playid and datediff(minute,d.created,dt.stopped)<=120
>     and d.userid=dt.userid)dt 
>    ),
>    cte2 as 
>    (
>   select top 1 *, 1 level from cte order by playid 
>   union all
>   select cte.* ,level+2 level from cte inner join cte2 on cte.stopped>cte2.minstopped
>    ),
>    cte3 as 
>    (
>   select *,row_number()over(partition by level order by playid) rn from cte2
>    )
>    SELECT playid,userid,created,minstopped stopped FROM CTE3 WHERE RN=1
> GO
> ```

Final output:

> | playid | userid | created | stopped |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:29:58.560 | 2021-01-30 04:16:25.947 |
> | 8 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:26:28.970 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
> | 21 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |
> | 23 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=11b7e05ba33e6e9e1d75fb530a26d40b)*

Comment: Thank u so much , I understood why you did that. Love u .

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a single query:

**Schema:**

> ```
> create table data (playid int,    userid varchar(10), created datetime,stopped datetime);
> insert into data values(1,'a01','01/30/2021 02:29:58.560','01/30/2021 02:40:56.558');
> insert into data values(2,'a01','01/30/2021 02:41:24.023','01/30/2021 02:55:24.113');
> insert into data values(3,'a01','01/30/2021 02:57:30.179','01/30/2021 03:11:14.867');
> insert into data values(4,'a01','01/30/2021 03:11:41.098','01/30/2021 03:22:50.156');
> insert into data values(5,'a01','01/30/2021 03:23:20.545','01/30/2021 03:36:37.027');
> insert into data values(6,'a01','01/30/2021 03:46:10.238','01/30/2021 03:59:17.526');
> insert into data values(7,'a01','01/30/2021 03:59:57.020','01/30/2021 04:16:25.948');
> insert into data values(8,'a01','01/30/2021 04:26:28.969','01/30/2021 04:30:11.863');
> insert into data values(9,'a01','01/30/2021 04:30:14.438','01/30/2021 04:41:42.232');
> insert into data values(10,'a01','01/30/2021 04:43:17.670','01/30/2021 04:45:10.443');
> insert into data values(11,'a01','01/30/2021 04:45:14.503','01/30/2021 04:47:07.082');
> insert into data values(12,'a01','01/30/2021 04:47:10.335','01/30/2021 04:49:30.960');
> insert into data values(13,'a01','01/30/2021 04:49:34.146','01/30/2021 04:50:54.460');
> insert into data values(14,'a01','01/30/2021 04:50:57.948','01/30/2021 05:11:01.246');
> insert into data values(15,'a01','01/30/2021 05:39:29.387','01/30/2021 05:41:39.509');
> insert into data values(16,'a01','01/30/2021 05:41:44.525','01/30/2021 05:43:38.231');
> insert into data values(17,'a01','01/30/2021 05:43:40.786','01/30/2021 05:54:40.711');
> insert into data values(18,'a01','01/30/2021 05:55:10.852','01/30/2021 05:58:24.262');
> insert into data values(19,'a01','01/30/2021 05:58:29.438','01/30/2021 06:00:50.871');
> insert into data values(20,'a01','01/30/2021 06:00:54.169','01/30/2021 06:12:37.210');
> insert into data values(21,'a01','01/30/2021 14:41:01.530','01/30/2021 14:53:01.349');
> insert into data values(22,'a01','01/30/2021 14:53:48.053','01/30/2021 15:05:09.533');
> insert into data values(23,'a01','01/31/2021 15:11:08.547','01/31/2021 15:11:37.565');
> insert into data values(24,'a01','01/31/2021 15:11:40.248','01/31/2021 15:13:40.218');
> insert into data values(25,'a01','01/31/2021 15:13:59.373','01/31/2021 15:31:54.100');
> insert into data values(26,'a01','01/31/2021 15:32:23.204','01/31/2021 15:46:33.994');
> insert into data values(27,'a01','01/31/2021 16:55:19.141','01/31/2021 17:03:43.464');
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
>   with cte as
>   (
>     select d.playid,d.userid,d.created,d.stopped,dt.minstopped from data d
>     outer apply (
>     select max(stopped) minstopped from data dt 
>     where  d.playid<dt.playid and datediff(minute,d.created,dt.stopped)<=120
>     and d.userid=dt.userid)dt 
>    ),
>    cte2 as 
>    (
>   select top 1 *, 1 level from cte order by playid 
>   union all
>   select cte.* ,level+2 level from cte inner join cte2 on cte.stopped>cte2.minstopped
>   ),
>   cte3 as 
>   (
>       select *,row_number()over(partition by level order by playid) rn from cte2
>   )
>   SELECT playid,userid,created,minstopped stopped FROM CTE3 WHERE RN=1
>   option (maxrecursion 0)     --if recursion level is more than 100 you need to mention it here
> ```

**Output:**

> | playid | userid | created | stopped |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | a01 | 2021-01-30 02:29:58.560 | 2021-01-30 04:16:25.947 |
> | 8 | a01 | 2021-01-30 04:26:28.970 | 2021-01-30 06:12:37.210 |
> | 21 | a01 | 2021-01-30 14:41:01.530 | 2021-01-30 15:05:09.533 |
> | 23 | a01 | 2021-01-31 15:11:08.547 | 2021-01-31 17:03:43.463 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3bc5b3032220a0e2a91e3c734216a338)*

Comment: Thank u so much , love u guy . I will review your query carefully to learn about my queries.

Comment: You are most welcome. It was an interesting problem to solve. You deserve an upvote. Best wishes.

Comment: I cannot understand your query even though I split them up, can you please explain a little bit about how to do it?